# How to determine the approximation factor for greedy vertex cover algorithm?

Tags: approximation, greedy-algorithms, vertex-cover

The algorithm iteratively picks the vertex with maximum degree and removes it and every incident edge of the vertex, until only vertices with degree of $0$ are left.

Formally:

$\text{GreedyVertexCover}(G)$:

$C\leftarrow \emptyset$

**While**
$(E\neq\emptyset)$

$\hspace{10pt}\text{Pick a vertex }v \text{ that has maximum degree}$

$\hspace{10pt}C\leftarrow C\cup \{v\}$

$\hspace{10pt}E=E\setminus\{e\in E:v\in e\}$

$\hspace{10pt}\text{Remove all vertices with degree 0}$

$\text{ Return } C$

My idea of the upper bound (please correct me if wrong): let $v_1, ..., v_n$ be the removed vertices. Define the cost of removing a vertex $v_i$ to be $c(v_i) = \cfrac{1}{\deg(v_i)}$. At any iteration $i$, among the vertices of the complementary set $\bar{C}$, there must exists a vertex with cost of at most $\cfrac{OPT}{n - i + 1}$.
Therefore the cost of constructing the set $C$ can be at most

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \cfrac{OPT}{n - i + 1} = \mathcal{O}(\log n) \cdot OPT $$

Comment: Your upper bound is correct, also you can check the analysis of the upper bound which presented in https://web.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr/~ozkahya/classes/cmp741/Reading/Approx.pdf .

Comment: If my answer is useful, you can accept it:)

Comment: What's your question?  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to identify a specific question.  I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 3):

The approximation factor can be $\Omega(\log n)$.

Consider a bipartite graph $G$ with a set $S_L$ with $n$ nodes on the left side. Also consider a collection of sets $S_{R,1},S_{R,2},\dots,S_{R,n}$ on the right side where each set $S_{R,i}$ has an edge to $i$ vertices in $S_{L}$ and no two vertices in $S_{R,i}$s have common edge . So $\lfloor{\frac{n}{i}}\rfloor$  in it. So the sum of size of $S_{R,i}$s
$$\sum_{i=0}^n |S_{R,i}|=\Theta(n\log n).$$

After running GreedyVertexCover on this instance, it select all nodes on right side, but the optimal solution was to select all nodes in $S_L$.

Consequently, $$\frac{ALG(G)}{OPT(G)}=\frac{n\log n}{n}=\log n.$$
So the approximation factor of your algorithm is $\Omega(\log n)$.